# iPhone - hide assistive touch view programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, touch, assistive

Does anyone know how to hide assistive touch view programmatically like Apple Music App does when playing video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SDK method to hide the assistive view.

Apple iPod App is done by Apple, so the App is probably using some private / undocumented SDK calls.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is. Go to Settings then General then Accessibility then Triple Click Home. Now choose Assistive Touch. Now whenever you want it to disappear just triple click the Home button on either the actual iPhone or using the Assustive Touch icon itself. Poof and its gone! To bring it back just triple click again.